# Running python file on angularjs using AJAX

Tags: python, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to run a python file on angularjs, the code is as follows:

```
    $scope.backup = function () {
        alert("test")
        const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

        this.rootObj = $firebaseObject(rootRef);
        console.log(this.rootObj,"firebase json");

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#confirm").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "~/writeFirebase.py",
                    data: {
                        firstname: "Jake",
                        lastname: "Wesley"
                    }
                })
                    .done(function (msg) {
                        alert("data saved:" + msg);
                    })
            })

    })
    }
```

Basically the python file called `writeFirebase.py` is used to write a file. I want to execute the python file when $scope.backup is called.

`writeFirebase.py` is as follows:

```
file = open("newfile.txt", "w")
file.write("hi")
file.write("and another line")
file.close()
```

However, after I execute the code, it seems like the `writeFirebase.py` file is not run because I am unable to find the text file.

Any idea where the bug is ?

Comment: `"~/writeFirebase.py"` is not an URL. What kind for Ajax request is the browser supposed to make?

Comment: @LutzHorn why is not a valid url path?

Comment: Not much detail provided. Are you seeing the alert? You need to first isolate if request is made or not and what it's status is in order to determine if problem is in client or server. Inspect in browser dev tools network for clues

Comment: @charlietfl yes the alert is shown. the console log is also logged. It is just the ajax part that is not working, not sure if it managed to read the python file.

Comment: If alert is shown then ajax is succeeding